# Is the idiom "in order" in order here?

Tags: word-choice

A user at my site can offer to delete an article, she can add an explanation to her deletion proposal if she feels her proposal isn't clear enough.

The message for asking for an explanation would be:
**"If you feel an explanation is (in order?), please provide one:"**
[and here comes a text-box for providing an explanation]

Replacing that message with:
**"If you feel your deletion proposal isn't clear enough, please provide one:"**
sounds awkward in its context.

Comment: I think "in order" is perfectly fine in this context. "Needed" would be another easy option.

Comment: The second version needs a subject, like *reason* or *explanation*, e.g. "If you feel *the reason for* your deletion proposal isn't clear enough, please provide one."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to replace "in order", I would suggest simply "necessary" or "pertinent"

> "If you feel an explanation is necessary, please provide one:"

or

> "If you feel an explanation is pertinent, please provide one:"

Answer (score 2):

"In order" is probably the best phrase here.  "Helpful"or "useful" would also be possible; "necessary" or "needed" change the meaning slightly.

And the reason your second suggestion sounds awkward is that it's ungrammatical; 'one' at the end has no noun to refer to.